# Subreports lose their design

Tags: crystal-reports

I've experienced a serious problem ... 4 reports that I have been working on for the past 2 months have just recently lost ALL their subreport designs.

Instead what I have now is the respective subreports have basically reverted back to the original design i.e. the subreport design about 2 months ago.

I am completely stumped .... any ideas ... cus this is the stuff of nightmares ...

Problem is that I decided not to save separate subreports for each main report so that it would make it easier to re-use one single subreport template. ... now I am regretting this cus not only does it take time to re-design the sub-reports ... it also takes time to debug/validate the subreport accuracy.

USE-CASE: How I am using the subreport is as follows:
1. There is one subreport template physically stored somewhere.
2. This subreport is inserted into each separate main report.
3. This subreport is then modified "within" the respective main report.
4. From experience, this modifications do not affect the original subreport template which still retains its original design.
5. The modifications continue to exist in the separate main reports ... even though the file name is actually the same as original subreport template.
6. From experience, this was an efficient and logical way to work ... hence saved me the hassle of having separate (but slightly modified) copies of the same subreport being physically dedicated to each main report.
7. This seemed to work until disaster struck ... without any explanation or reason.

Note:- I usually did manual version control of the report myself i.e. I saved physically separate versions of the same main report once I make changes. This diff versions existed both a local system and a separate physical shared network folder. Hence this problem is not merely a case of overwritten file.

The astonishing thing is that when the problem occurred, it affected all the versions irrespective of where it was stored ... which means the problem was very fundamental.

---

Edit:

The reports are now "all" working again ... but problem is that there is still absolutely no explanation for why they initially "all" reverted back to the old design of the subreport.

Seems my approach of sharing a single sub-report amongst main reports (as explained earlier) is not stable and hence quite a unique way of doing things. Should have suspected that something was not quite right because I have experience similar in the past but ... somehow thought I was the one not doing something right ...

I have now started dedicating a specific physical subreport to each main report (as suggested by Company supporting my Employers Crystal Report installations) ... as I simply no longer trust that my former approach would still not throw up the same behaviours in future once the reports enter production scenario.

Comment: Of course, you are using a version control tool, so you can retrieve the most recent checked-in version, or failing that you can restore from your last backup...?

Answer (score 0):

Did you have 'Re-import When Opening' enabled on the subreports?  If so, perhaps the source sub-RPT files were moved and CR was consequently unable to open them, resulting in what you are experiencing.

I've never seen this behavior in my 15 years or so working w/ the product.

Comment: just checked to confirm your suggestion ... so "No" the "Re-import When Opening" was not checked ...

Answer (score 0):

Is it just the design that changes back to how it was 2 months ago or is the data that age aswell?

If you are still getting the data from the subreport it would seem that it is still accessing the sub-report, but not the version you intended. In crystal if you right click on the sub-report and go to 'edit subreport' see if that is the right file and in the right location. Also check that you are not opening an older version of the main report that is still pointing to older versions of the sub report.

If you aren't getting anything out of the report, check the subreport is still there and functioning as intended, and that both reports still contain the linking field.

If all else fails, check your emails. Ive been saved a few times through a previous version or instance of a document that i had sent to someone earlier and found in my sent items!

NB I'm still a bit of a crystal noob

Comment: its was just the design the data is still correct on the datebase. I have resorted to redesigning the reports from memory and notes. Even the Company supporting the Crystal Report installation does not have any idea of such happening. Its seems my approach to using seems a little unique and efficient ... but sadly unstable as shown by my experience. Hence I have now reverted back to using a specific physical subreport for each main report instead of sharing a subreport amongst many main reports. This is clearly not efficient but it seems thats the only way to solve the instability problem.

Comment: Whilst being a frustrating experience, i cant see how that is a much more stable (and definitely not a scalable solution). I'm not sure how many reports you have using these subreports, but if you have multiple copies of essentially the same report, every time you want to make a change, you are going to have to make some sort of register to manually remember which reports were using the clone files and where they were stored, and everytime you make an update it will have to be manual. I used to do that, have since moved to sharing subreports, and it is a life saver

Comment: 1. it is definitely not scalable for sure cause its really slowing me down right now ... notice that even @Craig said he had not experience such in 15years.                                                                  2. I have learnt that until SAP tells me why sharing the sub-reports resulted in the nightmarish experience then I no option but to take the less efficient path ... even our 3rd party support acknowledged that my initial approach was clearly efficient